# Access all TabBar buttons and UIButtons programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in **UIViewController** and I want to access all UIButtons and TabBarButtons to disable them.

I tried with, and some other variations, but not working.

```
for (UITabBarItem *item in self.tabBarController.tabBarItem)
{
    item.enabled = enable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the whole window interaction by adding:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Enable interaction again with:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]isIgnoringInteractionEvents])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}
```

Comment: I do like this answer more.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this instead for disabling UITabBarItems (confirmed working for me):

```
for (UITabBarItem *item in self.tabBarController.tabBar.subviews)
{
    item.enabled = NO;
}
```

And to disable all UIButtons in your view, simply:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.view.subviews)
{
    button.enabled = NO;
}
```